# When ploting a line graph receiving memory warning and app crases in coreplot / ios 8?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, ios8.1

[image]I am Segmented Controller to show three graph.when i switch from one controller to other then app crashes.

I am using following code.

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot {
    if(mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"BabyWeight"] == YES || [plot.identifier isEqual:@"BabyLength"] == YES ) {

            return [_sendedArr count];
        }
        else {
            return [self.growthArr count];
        }
    }
    if(mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex ==1) {

        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"sendedWeight"] == YES) {

            return [_sendedArr count];
        }
        else {
            return [self.dancisArr count];
        }
    }

    if(mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"BabyPI"] == YES) {

            return [_sendedArr count];
        }
        else{
            return [self.pIArr count];
        }
    }
    return [self.growthArr count];


}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    if(mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex ==0) {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"BabyWeight"] == YES) {
            NSDictionary * dic = [_sendedArr objectAtIndex:index];
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"ga"];
                    break;

                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"weight"];

                    break;
            }
        }
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"BabyLength"] == YES) {
            NSDictionary * dic = [_sendedArr objectAtIndex:index];
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"ga"];
                    break;

                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"lenght"];

                    break;
            }
        }

        else{

            NSLog(@"fieldEnum%@",_sendedArr);
            NSDictionary * dic = [self.growthArr objectAtIndex:index];
            // NSLog(@"fieldEnum%lu",(unsigned long)CPTScatterPlotFieldY2);
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:

                    return [dic valueForKey:@"Weeks"];

                    break;

                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG1"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG2"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt1"];


                    } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG3"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt2"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG4"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt_1"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weightG5"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Wt_2"];
                    }


                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Length1"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Length"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Length2"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Length1"];

                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Length3"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Length2"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Length4"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Length_1"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"Length5"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Length_2"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"HC1"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"HC"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"HC2"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"HC1"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"HC3"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"HC2"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"HC4"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"HC_1"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"HC5"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"HC_2"];


                    }

                    break;


            }
        }

    }
    if(mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {

        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"sendedWeight"] == YES) {
            NSDictionary * dic = [_sendedArr objectAtIndex:index];
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"day"];
                    break;

                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"weight"];
                    break;
            }
        }
        else{
            //  NSLog(@"dancisChartArr%lu",(unsigned long)[dancisChartArr count]);

            NSDictionary * dic = [self.dancisArr objectAtIndex:index];
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"Age"];

                    break;
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight1"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_500"];

                    } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight2"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_1000"];

                    } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight3"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_1250"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight4"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_1500"];
                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight5"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_1750"];

                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight6"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_2000"];

                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight7"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_2250"];

                    }
                    else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"weight8"] == YES) {
                        return [dic valueForKey:@"Weight_2500"];
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex ==2) {
        if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"BabyPI"] == YES) {
            NSDictionary * dic = [_sendedArr objectAtIndex:index];
            float weightInt = [ [dic valueForKey:@"weight"] intValue];
            float lengthInt = [ [dic valueForKey:@"lenght"] intValue];
            float pi;
            pi = weightInt/(lengthInt*lengthInt*lengthInt);
            pi = pi *100;
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundUp];
            pi = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", pi] floatValue];
            NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:pi]];
            NSNumber *myNumber = [formatter numberFromString:numberString];
            NSLog(@"myNumber%@",myNumber);
            switch (fieldEnum) {
                case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"ga"];
                    break;

                case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                    return myNumber ;
                    break;
            }
        }
        NSDictionary * dic = [self.pIArr objectAtIndex:index];
        NSLog(@"self.pIArr%@",self.pIArr);
        switch (fieldEnum) {
            case CPTScatterPlotFieldX:

                return [dic valueForKey:@"GA"];

                break;
            case CPTScatterPlotFieldY:
                if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"PI10"] == YES) {
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"PI_10"];


                } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"PI50"] == YES) {
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"PI_25"];



                } else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"PI90"] == YES) {
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"PI_50"];

                }
                else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"PI25"] == YES) {
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"PI_75"];


                }
                else if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"PI75"] == YES) {
                    return [dic valueForKey:@"PI_90"];

                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return [NSDecimalNumber zero];
}
```

when plot drown that time app crashes and give memory warning .please give any solution  solving this.

Comment: That's a lot of plots. Are they all visible at the same time? How big is the graph (pixel dimensions)? How many data points does each one have?

Comment: Yes .I want to show at one time.when segment changed  to growth that time growth graph.when segment changed dancis that time dancis graph.   In growth array there are 18 plot each having array count my array count is 29 . dancis = 9 plot and  array count=50. PI = 6 plot and PI array count=16. please give solution

Comment: how to give limit .its zoom properly but zoom in having problem.please find the screen shot.

Comment: Have you run Instruments and checked for leaks and other memory management problems? It might be related to switching view controllers.